# ruby gem test fails

Tags: ruby, automated-tests

I'm trying to write my first Ruby gem, and so far I think it's all good-- however, my test fails to run with the error:

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'new' for myGemName:Module`

I have defined an initialize function in the main class:

```
def initialize(my_variable = false)
    if (my_variable) 
      self.set_variable = my_variable
    end
end
```

I get the same error when running from `irb`: `t = myGemName.new`

Comment: You can't `.new` modules. Try adding a class inside your module and try initializing it like: `myGemName::MyClass.new()`

Comment: @PascalRaszyk-- thanks, add this as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @PascalRaszyk answer in the comments, the correct solution is that you can't use `.new` against a module. So I needed to create a class inside the module, then use `myGemName::MyClass.new()` in the test to use the `initialize` method.